# Data sampling in google analytics goal flow report

Tags: google-analytics

The goal flow report on my google analytics account shows some strange sampling behavior. While I can usually select up to a month of data before sampling starts it seems to be different for the goal flow report.

As soon as I select more than one day of data the used data set is getting smaller very fast. At three days the report ist based on only 50% of the sessions, which, according to analytics, comes to only 35 sessions.

Has anyone experienced a similar behavior of sampling although only very small data-sets are used?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about google analytics the application sampling data and therefor  not programing related.  Might be better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sampling is induced when your request is calculation-intensive; there's no 'garunteed point at which it trips.

Goal flow complexity will increase exponentially as you add goals, so even a low number of goals might make this report demand a lot of processing.

Meanwhile you'll find that moast of the standard reports can cover large periods of time without sampling; they are preaggreated, so it's very cheap to load them.

If you want to know more about sampling, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37386181/5815149