# Google Core Analytics API - Data accuracy

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I have a Console App. which downloads the Acquisitions Report by querying the Google Analytics Core API.

Here is a screenshot of my query as shown on [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/):

[image]

I am unable to obtain a complete match of Goal Completions data between the API Data Output and the Analytics web interface. The variance is not too high but it exists. The Query Explorer and my Code Extract both match, but again, both of them mismatch with the data shown on the Analytics Web Interface.

All query parameters match 100%; including dates, Profile ID, ..etc.

I read articles online such as [this one](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/02/can-you-trust-your-google-analytics-data) and [this one](http://www.evancarmichael.com/library/abhishek-bhardwaj/Google-Analytics--How-Accurate-is-it.html), which elaborate on the inaccuracy of the Goal Completions data in google analytics, I wonder, could this be likely what is happening here?

Could this be related to bots and spiders? How do I exclude these from the query by using code?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about data accuracy in general or about the difference between web interface and api (both would be duplicates, but of different questions) ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I am asking about the difference (mismatch) between the web interface and the API Data Output.

Comment: Is there sampling?

Comment: @JBrazier I don't think there is; how do I know? I haven't done anything to include it. I am a newbie to this actually. Many thanks.

Comment: @t_plusplus In the Analytics Web Interface, it should give the sample percentage in the top right, just under the date selector. For more information about sampling, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37386181/5815149