# difference in analytics data v4 core reporting api

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

There seems to be a difference in data on dashboard and api v4. i also tried query explorer(uses v3 api i guess) and data is still different from api v4 data. Thing is if i request data for 50 days the data is correct but when i increase it to 80 days of more there is difference in data. i am using three dimensions ( date , camapign, source/medium) and one metric ( sessions ).

what could be the possible reason ? also i didn't supply anything for the sampling level in the api which case it was supposed to be default , sampling level in the query explorer is set to default . but still there is difference in the data.

What could be the possible reason for the difference?

EDIT : **diff in data**

```
{
        "metrics": [
          {
            "values": [
              "0"

              "0.0"

              "0.0"

              "0.0"

              "0.0"

              "1.6165413533834587"

              "0"

              "118"

              "133"

              "84"
            ]
          }
        ]

        "dimensions": [
          "20160911"

          "SOME_CAMAPIGN"

          "SOURCE / MEDIUM"
        ]
      }
```

the number 133 is sessions for the provided dimendions( cpaign,date,source /medium ) on web interface it shows 137 for the exact same dimensions

Comment: Mind posting some examples of the differences in data?

Comment: @DaImTo i have included the data in the question

Comment: Give me a few minutes to see if I can recreate it.  I will get back to you

Comment: @DaImTo i think my question is related to the anser here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372114/google-analytics-sampled-data-presents-more-sessions-than-api-query/37386181#37386181. as i am using 3 dimensions and high date range . could that be the reason for slight difference. (as mentioned in the answer of that question)

Comment: you need more data before sampling is going to kick in.  If your data was sampled the API would have returned the info to you.  you would be seeing samplesReadCounts and samplingSpaceSizes in the response

Comment: @DaImTo the response above is just a single elemnet of total results. i am getting close to 6000 rows for date range of 80 days. when i did for 550 days data was correct. could sampling be the issue. also how does api informs about sampling?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129418/discussion-between-daimto-and-anekix).